# Printing output of a variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am writing my first code using Shiny in Rstudio, it takes a file input (CSV file and prints the plot in main panel. After printing the plot I am trying to print the value of variables I passed to plot to observe their value which I am unable to do. It prints them in the Rstudio console. Second, I am looking to create a dataframe of those variables and download a CSV file containing those values. Hope I have explained the query. I am copying the code underneath.

I am able to print the plot in the browser. But variables are getting printed in console (rstudio) I need them in browser window underneath the plot and download a CSV file containing the dataframe of the these variables. I would appreciate if someone could please guide me about this.

```
structure(list(Point1 = c(9999, 9999, 433.333, 9999, 1433.333, 
33.333, 4283.333, 9999, 33.333, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 0.033, 
1323.333, 883.333, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 433.333, 1433.333, 
0.633, 9999, 9999, 9999, 33.333, 9999, 133.333, 433.333, 433.333, 
0.003, 4023.333, 33.333, 423.333, 1323.333, 423.333, 1323.333, 
4323.333, 2073.333, 1323.333, 1323.333, 1323.333, 1323.333, 1323.333, 
33.333, 123.333, 3363.333, 123.333, 0.333, 423.333), Point2 = c(4433.333, 
4433.333, 133.333, 4133.333, 433.333, 3.333, 1283.333, 4433.333, 
3.333, 4433.333, 4433.333, 4433.333, 4433.333, 0.003, 423.333, 
433.333, 4433.333, 4433.333, 4433.333, 4433.333, 133.333, 433.333, 
0.333, 4358.333, 4433.333, 4433.333, 3.333, 4433.333, 33.333, 
133.333, 133.333, NA, 1323.333, 3.333, 123.333, 423.333, 123.333, 
423.333, 1323.333, 1323.333, 423.333, 423.333, 423.333, 423.333, 
423.333, 3.333, 33.333, 1323.333, 33.333, 0.033, 123.333), OUTP1 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), Types = c(NA, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 
NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("Point1", "Point2", 
"OUTP1", "Types"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -51L
))

options(scipen=999)
library(survival)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
titlePanel("Survival analysis step1"),
tags$hr(),
sidebarPanel(
fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
           multiple = FALSE,
           accept = c("text/csv",
                      "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                      ".csv")),

tags$hr(),

checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

 radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
              choices = c(Comma = ",",
                          Semicolon = ";",
                          Tab = "\t"),
              selected = ","),

 radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
              choices = c(None = "",
                          "Double Quote" = '"',
                          "Single Quote" = "'"),
              selected = '"'),

 tags$hr(),

 radioButtons("disp", "Display",
              choices = c(Head = "head",
                          All = "all"),
              selected = "head")
 ),
mainPanel(
plotOutput('plot'),
textOutput("selected_var")
     )
               )
server <- function(input, output) {
output$plot <- renderPlot({

req(input$file1)

testpeanut1 <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                   header = input$header,
                   sep = input$sep,
                   quote = input$quote)
    print(dput(testpeanut1))
testpeanut1[is.na(testpeanut1)]<-"0"
testpeanut1$modified_Point1<-ifelse(as.numeric(testpeanut1$Types) ==2, as.numeric(testpeanut1$Point2), as.numeric(testpeanut1$Point1))
testpeanut1$modified_Point2<-ifelse(as.numeric(testpeanut1$Types) ==2, as.numeric(testpeanut1$Point1), as.numeric(testpeanut1$Point2))
set.seed(1234567)
testpeanut1$Survial_analysis_obj<-Surv(as.numeric(testpeanut1$modified_Point2),as.numeric(testpeanut1$modified_Point1), as.numeric(testpeanut1$Types), type="interval")
model_log_N_obj<-survreg(formula= testpeanut1$Survial_analysis_obj~1, data=testpeanut1, dist="lognormal")
new1<-data.frame(1)
predmodel_log_N_obj<-predict(model_log_N_obj, newdata=new1, type='quantile', p=seq(0.001,0.99, by=0.0001), se.fit=TRUE)


    plot(predmodel_log_N_obj$fit, seq(0.001,0.99, by=0.0001), 
     type="l", col=2, lty=1, lwd=2, xlim=c(0.00001,100000000), 
     main="Plot description", 
     xlab="Caption",
     ylab = "probability",  
     log="x", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n") 
lines(exp(log(predmodel_log_N_obj$fit)+1.96* (predmodel_log_N_obj$se.fit)/ predmodel_log_N_obj$fit),seq(0.001,0.99, by=0.0001), type="l", col=2, lty=2)
lines(exp(log(predmodel_log_N_obj$fit)-1.96* (predmodel_log_N_obj$se.fit)/ predmodel_log_N_obj$fit),seq(0.001,0.99, by=0.0001), type="l", col=2, lty=2)

ED01_log_N_obj<-predict(model_log_N_obj, newdata=new1, type='quantile', p=0.01, se.fit=TRUE) #0.18
print(ED01_log_N_obj)
ED01_log_N_CL_obj <- exp(log(ED01_log_N_obj$fit)-1.96* (ED01_log_N_obj$se.fit)/ ED01_log_N_obj$fit)
print(ED01_log_N_CL_obj)
#ED01 upper confidence level - 0.75
ED01_log_N_CU_obj<- exp(log(ED01_log_N_obj$fit)+1.96* (ED01_log_N_obj$se.fit)/ ED01_log_N_obj$fit)
print(ED01_log_N_CU_obj)

df<-data.frame(ED01_log_N_CU_obj)
df$ED01_log_N_CL_obj<-ED01_log_N_CL_obj
df$ED01_log_N_objfit<-ED01_log_N_obj$fit

dput(testpeanut1)    
})

output$selected_var <- renderText("ED01_log_N_obj") 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Plot+printed variables in browser and CSV file either on click of a button etc. or as a link to download.

Comment: First, I think you missed a `{` after server. Second, you are putting everything under renderPlot, which might not be a practice. You are doing two separate things, one is a plot with fitted probability and prediction interval, the other is a data frame.  It's very hard to help without any actual data. I suggest you move the data frame part before the plot, and you can take advantage of the data frame to plot.  And, you may need actionButton to fulfill your last request.

Comment: Hi @wxxyyyzz, thanks for your response. First of all, yes I missed { while copy pasting the code. Because it was my first time using shiny environment so I just moved all code into renderPlot block. With data frame outside renderplot do you mean the lines from read.CSV till predict()? If yes, I will try moving them. About the dataset sample would you please tell me how should I share dataset because I am not familiar with stackoverflow environment completely and do not know how to attach data set.

Comment: to share a dataframe on stackoverflow, use the function ```dput```. For example, ```dput(mtcars)``` gives the code to produce the dataframe ```mtcars``` (just replace it by the name of your dataframe, or of a subset of your dataframe)

Comment: Hi @wxxyyyzz I have updated the example with the dataset, hope it is now easy to get my issue resolved.

Comment: Hi @bretauv, thanks I used put to share my dataset as per your recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you only got the output in the console instead of Shiny because you used print rather than putting them into renderXXX. I tried to use your updated data as an csv input and the following should work. There is "()" after data because it's a reactive value that you call it like a function. Also, you might need to edit the extension of the downloaded file though.  I did not have time to clean the code up so there is still redundancy. Hopefully, it helps.

```
library(survival)
library(shiny)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
    titlePanel("Survival analysis step1"),
    tags$hr(),
    sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                  multiple = FALSE,
                  accept = c("text/csv",
                             "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                             ".csv")),

        tags$hr(),

        checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

        radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                     choices = c(Comma = ",",
                                 Semicolon = ";",
                                 Tab = "\t"),
                     selected = ","),

        radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                     choices = c(None = "",
                                 "Double Quote" = '"',
                                 "Single Quote" = "'"),
                     selected = '"'),

        tags$hr(),

        radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                     choices = c(Head = "head",
                                 All = "all"),
                     selected = "head"),

        downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
    ),
    mainPanel(
        plotOutput('plot'),
        tableOutput("selected_var")
    )
)
server <- function(input, output) {

    data <- reactive({
        req(input$file1)

        testpeanut1 <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                                header = input$header,
                                sep = input$sep,
                                quote = input$quote)
        testpeanut1[is.na(testpeanut1)] <- "0"
        testpeanut1$modified_Point1 <- ifelse(as.numeric(testpeanut1$Types)==2, as.numeric(testpeanut1$Point2), as.numeric(testpeanut1$Point1))
        testpeanut1$modified_Point2 <- ifelse(as.numeric(testpeanut1$Types)==2, as.numeric(testpeanut1$Point1), as.numeric(testpeanut1$Point2))
        testpeanut1$Survial_analysis_obj <- Surv(as.numeric(testpeanut1$modified_Point2),as.numeric(testpeanut1$modified_Point1), as.numeric(testpeanut1$Types), type="interval")

        model_log_N_obj<-survreg(formula= testpeanut1$Survial_analysis_obj~1, data=testpeanut1, dist="lognormal")
        new1<-data.frame(1)
        predmodel_log_N_obj<-predict(model_log_N_obj, newdata=new1, type='quantile', p=seq(0.001,0.99, by=0.0001), se.fit=TRUE)

        ED01_log_N_obj <- predict(model_log_N_obj, newdata=new1, type='quantile', p=0.01, se.fit=TRUE) #0.18
        ED01_log_N_CL_obj <- exp(log(ED01_log_N_obj$fit)-1.96* (ED01_log_N_obj$se.fit)/ ED01_log_N_obj$fit)
        #ED01 upper confidence level - 0.75
        ED01_log_N_CU_obj <- exp(log(ED01_log_N_obj$fit)+1.96* (ED01_log_N_obj$se.fit)/ ED01_log_N_obj$fit)

        dfOut<-data.frame(ED01_log_N_CU_obj)
        dfOut$ED01_log_N_CL_obj<-ED01_log_N_CL_obj
        dfOut$ED01_log_N_objfit<-ED01_log_N_obj$fit

        return(list(df = testpeanut1,
                    predmodel = predmodel_log_N_obj,
                    summary = dfOut))
    })


    output$plot <- renderPlot({

        plot(data()$predmodel$fit, seq(0.001,0.99, by=0.0001), 
             type="l", col=2, lty=1, lwd=2, xlim=c(0.00001,100000000), 
             main="Plot description", 
             xlab="Caption",
             ylab = "probability",  
             log="x", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n") 
        lines(exp(log(data()$predmodel$fit)+1.96* (data()$predmodel$se.fit)/ data()$predmodel$fit),seq(0.001,0.99, by=0.0001), type="l", col=2, lty=2)
        lines(exp(log(data()$predmodel$fit)-1.96* (data()$predmodel$se.fit)/ data()$predmodel$fit),seq(0.001,0.99, by=0.0001), type="l", col=2, lty=2)

    })

    output$selected_var <- renderTable(data()$summary)

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

        filename = "output.csv",
        content = function(file) {
            write.csv(data()$df, file, row.names = FALSE)
        },
        contentType = "text/csv"
    )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Dear @wxxyyyzz, thanks a lot. It works fine. I will try improving it.

Comment: Dear @wxxyyyzz, I have a quick question.  I am using as recommended by you 
    output$selected_var <- renderTable(data()$summary). I did another experiment and put a tabset on the page and called same on the click of the tabs. Everything works but when I put on one of the tabs

      output$display_var <- renderTable(data()$df)
It gives an error 

   " number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

But instead of rendertable If I use renderprint just to check, it prints the dataset.

Would you please explain why it is happening and how to resolve this error?